# Dynamically Editing Pipeline Config for Tensorflow Object Detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, object-detection-api

I'm using tensorflow object detection API, and I want to be able to edit config file dynamically in python, which looks like this. I thought of using protocol buffers library in python, but I'm not sure how to go about.

```
model {
ssd {
num_classes: 1
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 300
    width: 300
  }
}
feature_extractor {
  type: "ssd_inception_v2"
  depth_multiplier: 1.0
  min_depth: 16
  conv_hyperparams {
    regularizer {
      l2_regularizer {
        weight: 3.99999989895e-05
      }
    }
    initializer {
      truncated_normal_initializer {
        mean: 0.0
        stddev: 0.0299999993294
      }
    }
    activation: RELU_6
    batch_norm {
      decay: 0.999700009823
      center: true
      scale: true
      epsilon: 0.0010000000475
      train: true
    }
  }
 ...
 ...
```

}

Is there a simple/easy way to change specific values for fields like height in image_resizer -> fixed_shape_resizer from say 300 to 500? And write back the file with modified values without changing anything else?

EDIT:
Though answer provided by @DmytroPrylipko worked for most of the parameters in the config, I face some issues with "composite field"..

That is, if we have configuration like:

```
train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "/tensorflow/data/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/tensorflow/models/data/train.record"
  }
}
```

And I add this line to edit input_path:

```
 pipeline_config.train_input_reader.tf_record_input_reader.input_path = "/tensorflow/models/data/train100.record"
```

It throws error:

```
TypeError: Can't set composite field
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, using Protobuf Python API is quite easy:

**edit_pipeline.py**:

```
import argparse

import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import text_format
from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2


def parse_arguments():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    parser.add_argument('pipeline')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    parser.add_argument('output')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    return parser.parse_args()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        


def main():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    args = parse_arguments()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    pipeline_config = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()                                                                                                                                                                                                          

    with tf.gfile.GFile(args.pipeline, "r") as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        proto_str = f.read()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    pipeline_config.model.ssd.image_resizer.fixed_shape_resizer.height = 300                                                                                                                                                                                          
    pipeline_config.model.ssd.image_resizer.fixed_shape_resizer.width = 300                                                                                                                                                                                           

    config_text = text_format.MessageToString(pipeline_config)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    with tf.gfile.Open(args.output, "wb") as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        f.write(config_text)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    main()
```

The way I call the script:

```
TOOL_DIR=tool/tf-models/research

(
   cd $TOOL_DIR
   protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
)

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$TOOL_DIR:$TOOL_DIR/slim

python3 edit_pipeline.py pipeline.config pipeline_new.config
```

**Composite fields**

In case of repeated fields, you must treat them as arrays (e.g. use `extend()`, `append()` methods):

```
pipeline_config.train_input_reader.tf_record_input_reader.input_path[0] = '/tensorflow/models/data/train100.record'
```

**Eval Input reader error**

This is a common error trying to edit the composite field. ( *"no attribute tf_record_input_reader found" in case of eval_input_reader* )

It's mentioned below in @latida's answer. 
Fix that by setting it as an array field.

```
pipeline_config.eval_input_reader[0].label_map_path  = label_map_full_path
pipeline_config.eval_input_reader[0].tf_record_input_reader.input_path[0] = val_record_path
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you the answer, but I am facing issues with "Composite fields".. Could you please suggest me how to fix that? I've updated the question with more details.. Thanks again..

Comment: `pipeline_config.train_input_reader.tf_record_input_reader.input_path[0] = '/tensorflow/models/data/train100.record'`. See the updated answer. More on composite fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376190/attributeerror-assignment-not-allowed-to-composite-field-task-in-protocol-mes

Comment: You are awesome! Finally composite fields issue resolved! Thank you so much!!

Comment: For me changing input_path and label_map_path works fine for train_input_reader but shows an error of "no attribute tf_record_input_reader found" in case of eval_input_reader

Comment: What about a composite field in the case where you want to replace object_detection.protos.image_resizer_pb2.FixedShapeResizer with object_detection.protos.image_resizer_pb2.KeepAspectRatioResizer?

Comment: @Austin Did you find the way to replace to FixedShapeResizer with KeepAspectRatioResizer ? I need to do replace KeepAspectRatioResizer with FixedShapeResizer in Faster RCNN.

Comment: Thanks. This can also be done using dictionaries with  `google.protobuf.json_format.ParseDict(dic, pipeline_config)` (also cf. `google.protobuf.json_format.MessageToDict`) [link to the doc](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html#google.protobuf.json_format.ParseDict)

Answer (score 3):

This is the same above code with small changes that suit the tensorflow V2.

```
import argparse

import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import text_format
from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2

def parse_arguments():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    parser.add_argument('pipeline')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    parser.add_argument('output')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    return parser.parse_args()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        


def main():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    args = parse_arguments()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    pipeline_config = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()                                                                                                                                                                                                          

    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(args.pipeline, "r") as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        proto_str = f.read()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

    pipeline_config.model.ssd.image_resizer.fixed_shape_resizer.height = 300                                                                                                                                                                                          
    pipeline_config.model.ssd.image_resizer.fixed_shape_resizer.width = 300                                                                                                                                                                                           

    config_text = text_format.MessageToString(pipeline_config) 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(args.output, "wb") as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        f.write(config_text)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found this to be a useful approach for overriding the object detection `pipeline.config`:

```
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection import model_lib_v2

PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH = 'path_to_your_pipeline.config'

# Load the pipeline config as a dictionary
pipeline_config_dict = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH)

# OVERRIDE EXAMPLES
# Example 1: Override the train tfrecord path
pipeline_config_dict['train_input_config'].tf_record_input_reader.input_path[0] = 'your/override/path/to/train.record'
# Example 2: Override the eval tfrecord path
pipeline_config_dict['eval_input_config'].tf_record_input_reader.input_path[0] = 'your/override/path/to/test.record'

# Convert the pipeline dict back to a protobuf object
pipeline_config = config_util.create_pipeline_proto_from_configs(pipeline_config_dict)

# EXAMPLE USAGE:
# Example 1: Run the object detection train loop with your overrides (has to be string representation)
model_lib_v2.train_loop(config_override=str(pipeline_config))
# Example 2: Save the pipeline config to disk
config_util.save_pipeline_config(config, 'path/to/save/new/pipeline.config)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new to programming but I wanted to share something that I was trying to do because the original question also gives me trouble.

Let's say I already have a config file on my computer and I've compiled all of my TF2 Object Detection protos but now I want to change the preprocessing. I use python.

First, I'll get my config file as a python dictionary

```
from object_detection.utils import config_util

# PATH_TO_MY_CONFIG_FILE can be whatever the path is to your config file 
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(PATH_TO_MY_CONFIG_FILE)
```

Next, I'd like to check what data augmentations / preprocessing I currently have.

```
print(configs['train_config'].data_augmentation_options)
print(type(configs['train_config'].data_augmentation_options[0]))
```

> [random_horizontal_flip {
> }
> , random_scale_crop_and_pad_to_square {
> output_size: 512
> scale_min: 0.10000000149011612
> scale_max: 2.0
> }
> ]

> <class 'object_detection.protos.preprocessor_pb2.PreprocessingStep'>

It looks to me like *configs['train_config'].data_augmentation_options* is a python list containing instances of the class *PreprocessingStep* that is from the file *preprocessor_pb2.py*

When I previously tried running code from the TF2 Object Detection github repo there was some code that compiled protos for me. The protocompiler took my preprocessor.proto file and created a new file from it called preprocessor_pb2.py that is now on my computer. In this python file there is a class called *PreprocessingStep*.

I will use this script to make a new preprocessing step for my configuration.

```
from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2

# Construct a new PreprocessingStep object
my_new_data_augmentation = preprocessor_pb2.PreprocessingStep()
# I would like to randomly change some color images to gray with %20 probability
my_new_data_augmentation.random_rgb_to_gray.probability = 0.2
print(my_new_data_augmentation)
```

> random_rgb_to_gray {
> probability: 0.20000000298023224
> }

A PreprocessingStep step object has a lot of different fields. You can look inside the file *preprocessor_pb2.py* for a list of fields you can modify or you can look at the [preprocessor.proto on the TF2 OD Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto) at the list of messages (These are the text in red). The messages are the names of the fields you can change.

Once you've selected a field to modify you can further set the optional parameters. In my example 'probability' is the only parameter you can modify for the 'random_rgb_to_gray' preprocessing step (I think).

Also, I don't think you can set your PreprocessingStep object to have multiple preprocessing fields. For example, if I did

```
my_new_data_augmentation.random_rgb_to_gray.probability = 0.2
my_new_data_augmentation.random_adjust_hue.max_delta = 0.1
print(my_new_data_augmentation)
```

> random_adjust_hue {
> max_delta: 0.10000000149011612
> }

things will just get overwritten.

I guess, now my preprocessing step is random_adjust_hue. I will go ahead and add this to my data augmentations now using list.append()

```
configs['train_config'].data_augmentation_options.append(my_new_data_augmentation)
print(configs['train_config'].data_augmentation_options)
```

> [random_horizontal_flip {
> }
> , random_scale_crop_and_pad_to_square {
> output_size: 512
> scale_min: 0.10000000149011612
> scale_max: 2.0
> }
> , random_adjust_hue {
> max_delta: 0.10000000149011612
> }
> ]

Now I can save my configs using the usual config_util.create_pipeline_proto_from_configs() method.

Like I said I'm very new to programming and I don't know if this idea causes some bugs that I'm not aware of but I wanted to share this in case somebody else finds this helpful as a starting place to build on I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to others post in this thread, this is what I'm doing

My `model variables`:

```py
##change chosen model to deploy different models available in the TF2 object detection zoo
MODELS_MATRIX = {
    'SSD-MobileNet-v2-320x320': {
        'name': 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8',
        'file': 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz',
        'checkpoint': 'checkpoint/ckpt-0',
        'url': 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz'
    },
    'SSD-MobileNet-V2-FPNLite-640x640': {
        'name': 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8',
        'file': 'ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz',
        'checkpoint': 'checkpoint/ckpt-0',
        'url': 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz'
    },
    'SSD-ResNet101-V1-FPN-640x640': {
        'name': 'ssd_resnet101_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8',
        'file': 'ssd_resnet101_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz',
        'checkpoint': 'checkpoint/ckpt-0',
        'url': 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_resnet101_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz'
    }
}    

# local paths
local_pre_trainied_models_path = '/content/workspace/training/pre-trained-models'
local_models_path = '/content/workspace/training/models'

# model variables
chosen_model = 'SSD-ResNet101-V1-FPN-640x640'
model_url    = MODELS_MATRIX[chosen_model]['url']
model_file   = MODELS_MATRIX[chosen_model]['file']
model_name   = MODELS_MATRIX[chosen_model]['name']

model_fine_tune_checkpoint = local_pre_trainied_models_path +'/'+ MODELS_MATRIX[chosen_model]['name'] + '/' + MODELS_MATRIX[chosen_model]['checkpoint']
model_fine_tune_checkpoint_type = "detection"

# Set this to false if you are not training on a TPU
model_use_bfloat16 = False

# For faster training time, images should be resized to 300x300 and then annotated
# Images should contain the objects of interest at various scales, angles, lighting conditions, locations
# For acceptable results - mAP@0.5 of 0.9 the model was trained with batch size of 24
# and 5000 steps. this takes about 1h using 2 augmentations. 
# using 5 augmentations it takes about 2h 
# A step means using a single batch of data. larger batch, less steps required
model_num_steps = 13000  

#Number of evaluation steps.
model_num_eval_steps = 50
model_batch_size     = 16
model_iou_threshold  = 0.50
model_num_classes    = 1

# tf records and labels
model_train_record_file = '/content/workspace/training/annotations/train/license-plates.tfrecord'
model_train_label_map_pbtxt_file = '/content/workspace/training/annotations/train/license-plates_label_map.pbtxt'

model_test_record_file = '/content/workspace/training/annotations/test/license-plates.tfrecord'
model_test_label_map_pbtxt_file = '/content/workspace/training/annotations/test/license-plates_label_map.pbtxt'
```

Configuring my pipeline`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import text_format
from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2

custom_pipeline_file = f"{local_models_path}/anrp_{model_name}/pipeline.config"

pipeline_conf = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()

# merge conf
with tf.io.gfile.GFile(custom_pipeline_file, "r") as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    proto_str = f.read()
    text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_conf)

# model
pipeline_conf.model.ssd.num_classes = model_num_classes
pipeline_conf.model.ssd.post_processing.batch_non_max_suppression.iou_threshold = model_iou_threshold

# train_config
pipeline_conf.train_config.batch_size = model_batch_size
pipeline_conf.train_config.num_steps = model_num_steps
pipeline_conf.train_config.fine_tune_checkpoint = model_fine_tune_checkpoint
pipeline_conf.train_config.fine_tune_checkpoint_type = model_fine_tune_checkpoint_type
pipeline_conf.train_config.use_bfloat16 = model_use_bfloat16

# train_input_reader
pipeline_conf.train_input_reader.label_map_path = model_train_label_map_pbtxt_file
pipeline_conf.train_input_reader.tf_record_input_reader.input_path[0] = model_train_record_file

# eval_config
pipeline_conf.eval_config.metrics_set[0] = "coco_detection_metrics"
pipeline_conf.eval_config.use_moving_averages = False


# eval_input_reader
pipeline_conf.eval_input_reader[0].label_map_path = model_test_label_map_pbtxt_file
pipeline_conf.eval_input_reader[0].tf_record_input_reader.input_path[0] = model_test_record_file

config_text = text_format.MessageToString(pipeline_conf) 

# debug
print(pipeline_conf)
print(config_text)

# override my conf
# with tf.io.gfile.GFile(custom_pipeline_file, "wb") as f:                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#     f.write(config_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pipeline_config.eval_input_reader[0].label_map_path  = label_map_full_path
pipeline_config.eval_input_reader[0].tf_record_input_reader.input_path[0] = val_record_path
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. You can add a comment to the existing question